# C++ template equivalent in Java

Tags: java

I am from a C++ background and new to Java. Currently I am programming in Java and I have three different functions doing the same thing, but with different data types:

```
DataConnection1 Db1;
DataConnection1 Db2;
DataConnection1 Db3;

fetchIdD1(Db1, Db2)
{
    //`enter code here`
}
fetchIdD2(Db2, Db2)
{
    //`enter code here`
}
fetchIdD3(Db3, Db2)
{
    //`enter code here`
}
```

I know that in C++ I could easily convert to one function using templates.

Does Java have an equivalent to templates so that I could also do this?

Comment: LONG time since I did C++, but wouldn't that be the simular as generics?

Comment: See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html  

Given you're new to Java, I suggest you read the rest of the Java tutorial also. Generics is a (relatively) advanced Java topic, so start with the basics.

Comment: In your code you have three variables `Db1, Db2, Db3` of the same datatype `DataConnection1`. To make your question clear you can provide a *valid* C++ code which you want to convert to Java.

Answer (score 2):

Java does not have templates, nor anything more than vaguely similar. It does, however, have something called *generics*, which support a tiny subset of the things C++ templates can do (though in a type-unsafe manner). They even look vaguely similar to C++ templates in the syntax.

You declare a generic class like this:

```
class MyClass<T> {
    public MyClass(T x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    T getX() {
        return this.x;
    }
    private T x;
};
```

You use it like this:

```
MyClass<String> str = new MyClass<>("Hello World!");
System.out.println(str.getX()); // prints Hello World!
```

You cannot use primitive types as the type arguments. You need to use the boxed forms instead:

```
MyClass<Integer> i = new MyClass<>(42);
System.out.println(i.getX()); // prints 42
```

You declare a generic method like this:

```
public <T> T getSomething(int i) {
    T my_thing = new T(); // I can't remember, this might be a compile error
    return my_thing;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
getSomething<String>(7);
```

Of course, if T is used in the argument list, you can omit the `<String>` part.

You can also force the type parameter to implement some interface with the syntax `<T extends Comparable<T>>` - this example means that you can call `.compareTo` on any objects of type `T`. There's also a `<T super YourClass>` syntax, but I never quite understood what it meant.

---

Remember how I said at the top that generics are not type-safe? This is due to *type erasure*. In a nutshell, generics are compiled exactly as if all type parameters are actually `Object`. They provide a level of type-checking at the compilation stage, but at runtime this extra type information is lost - the example `MyClass` declaration above doesn't produce separate versions of the class for each type parameter it was used with (as would be the case with C++ templates), but just one single class declaration which replaces all `T` with `Object`. It's possible to declare a `MyClass` without type parameters (this is called a *raw type*), and there are a number of pitfalls you can hit here, for example in the standard library container classes.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. It helped me lot.